# Jsp page is not accepting css rules under Spring Mvc project (running on Tomcat 7)

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, tomcat7, tiles

I am trying to apply a css rule in a jsp page running under spring mvc environment.
webapp/css/mystyles.css :

```
.center{
    margin: auto; text-align: center;
}

h1{
    color: red;
}
```

webapp/WEB-INF/jsp/Layout.jsp:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="tiles" uri="http://tiles.apache.org/tags-tiles" %>

<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<html>
<head>
    <title><tiles:insertAttribute name="title" ignore="true"/></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../css/mystyles.css" media="screen" />
</head>
<body>
    <table border="1" cellspacing="2" align="center">
        <tr>
            <td height="30" colspan="2">
                <tiles:insertAttribute name="header"/>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td height="250" width="150">
                <tiles:insertAttribute name="menu"/>
            </td>
            <td width="400">
                <tiles:insertAttribute name="body"/>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td height="30" colspan="2">
                <tiles:insertAttribute name="footer"/>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

And here is part of the produced web page code I am getting with firebug :

```
<head>
<title>Being Java Guys | Tiles Integration</title>
<link media="screen" href="../../css/mystyles.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
<html><head><title>Apache Tomcat/7.0.35 - Error report</title><style><!--H1 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:22px;} H2 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:16px;} H3 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:14px;} BODY {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:black;background-color:white;} B {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;} P {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;background:white;color:black;font-size:12px;}A {color : black;}A.name {color : black;}HR {color : #525D76;}--></style> </head><body><h1>HTTP Status 404 - </h1><HR size="1" noshade="noshade"><p><b>type</b> Status report</p><p><b>message</b> <u></u></p><p><b>description</b> <u>The requested resource is not available.</u></p><HR size="1" noshade="noshade"><h3>Apache Tomcat/7.0.35</h3></body></html>
</link>
</head>

<div class="center">
<h1>Header</h1>
</div>
```

Unfortunately I am not getting a red Header.

Comment: Is the css file read by the browser?

Comment: How can I check that?

Comment: Call the page up on your browser under a debugger. FireFox, Chrome and IE (current versions) all have them. They have a tag in the debugger to show you what files actually were loaded and what files failed to load.

Comment: yes. Firebug works nicely. There is a "network" tab, I think. The tab is over to the right, maybe next to last.

Comment: I have enabled the net tab but it shows nothing at all.

Comment: Reloading tomcat I am getting GET mystyles.css , (status) 404 not found

Comment: firebug will also show you the full URL where it tried to get the file, without the ../../.. stuff.

Comment: Yes, under the GET mystyles.css I see the following (http://localhost:8080/css/mystyles.css)

Comment: I believe that it has to do with proper spring mvc static file serving but both solutions I found here (http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-static-resources) are not working at all.

Answer (score 0):

You have to change something so the css file gets loaded.

Tomcat can't find it at "../../css/mystyles.css" (which you show as being `http://localhost/css/mystyles.css`" in firebug's net tab) so the URL in the  tag is either wrong or Tomcat is set up somehow wrong.

Hint: You can enter the URL for a css file in the browser address bar to try various things more easily as you change the Tomcat config or load files.

Answer (score 0):

You are messing server side file locations, and URLs.

In server-side `/WEB-INF/pages/../../css/mycss.css` would be your css, but not when it is a page rendered by a browser. Because on the browser your JSPs URL is something else.

You shall have a `<base>` tag in your `<head>` to specify relative URLs target, and then specify URL relative to that.

Comment: Please check my original post with its comments.I just want to serve static content but I have not managed to do it yet.

Answer (score 0):

Please add context path of application before css file path.

```
<%@ taglib prefix="tiles" uri="http://tiles.apache.org/tags-tiles" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>

<c:set var="contextPath" scope="request" value="${pageContext.request.contextPath}" />

<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<html>
<head>
    <title><tiles:insertAttribute name="title" ignore="true"/></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="${contextPath}/css/mystyles.css" media="screen" />
</head>
<body>
    <table border="1" cellspacing="2" align="center">
    <tr>
        <td height="30" colspan="2">
        <tiles:insertAttribute name="header"/>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td height="250" width="150">
        <tiles:insertAttribute name="menu"/>
        </td>
        <td width="400">
        <tiles:insertAttribute name="body"/>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td height="30" colspan="2">
        <tiles:insertAttribute name="footer"/>
        </td>
    </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```